# How to access private data member outside the class?

Tags: java

I am trying to access the private data member of inner class outside the outer class.

Please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You don't - that's the whole point of it being private.

The inner class can expose the data via a property, of course:

```
public class Outer {
    public class Inner {
        private final String name;

        public Inner(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}

public class Other {
    public void foo() {
        Outer outer = new Outer();
        Outer.Inner inner = outer.new Inner("Foo");
        // Can't access inner.name here...
        System.out.println(inner.getName()); // But can call getName
    }
}
```

... but if the inner class wants to keep it private, then you *shouldn't* try to access it.

Comment: Is there any benefits for designing it like that? I mean, if it's `private` for the class, why do they allow accessing it outside it (even if it's an *inner* class)..

Comment: Java is a fully object oriented programming language. Data hiding in other words, Encapsulation is a main feature in OOP. Best practice is setting all class attributes private and making all methods public including getter setter methods to access those private attributes.

Comment: @Nadun: It's not clear what you were replying to, but you don't just make all methods public... Maroun's comment was (I believe) in reply to a comment I made on his now-deleted answer, to the effect that private members of inner classes are accessible to their enclosing classes.

Comment: I just explain to @Maroun's question.

Comment: @Nadun: I think you were missing the context of the question, unfortunately. But again, I don't think it's a good idea to recommend that folks make *all* methods public.

Comment: Indeed, I was referring to Jon's comment to my deleted answer, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Create public getter setter methods inside the inner class for private variables. Then create an object and call them to access private data. You can't directly access private data.

Answer (score 0):

you cant access a private data. If ýou have other thoughts of accessing it use public getter method returning that private data.

Answer (score 0):

you can access private data member using getter method ex

```
package pack;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;

public class abc {
    private int num = 2;

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

}

class otherClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        abc obj = new abc();
        System.out.println(obj.getNum());
    }
}
```